# React Native: ListView.DataSource is not updating

Tags: react-native

I am trying to update `ListView.DataSource` after fetching data from server but its not happening. I have two components, one is imported in other. 
From base component I am trying to update `ListView.DataSource` in other component. Here is my code.

index.android.js

```
 import React, { Component } from "react";
 import { ListView, View, Button, AppRegistry } from "react-native";

 import OtherComponent from "./Components/OtherComponent";

 class MyApp extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
        movies: [{ title: "ABCD" }, { title: "EFGH" }]
    };
}

getTopics = () => {
    fetch("https://facebook.github.io/react-native/movies.json")
        .then(response => response.json())
        .then(responseText => {
            console.log(responseText.movies);
            this.setState({
                movies: responseText.movies
            });
        })
        .catch(error => {
            console.warn(error);
        });
};

render() {
    return (
        <View>
            <Button
                onPress={this.getTopics}
                title="Get Topics"
                color="#841584"
                accessibilityLabel="Learn more about this purple button"
            />
            <OtherComponent movies={this.state.movies} />
        </View>
    );
}
}

AppRegistry.registerComponent("MyApp", () => MyApp);
```

OtheComponent.js

```
 import React, { Component } from "react";
 import { View, ListView, Text, StyleSheet, Button } from "react-native";

 export default class FormativeRevisionList extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    const ds = new ListView.DataSource({
        rowHasChanged: (r1, r2) => r1 !== r2
    });
    this.state = {
        dataSource: ds.cloneWithRows(props.movies)
    };
}

render() {
    return (
        <View>
            <ListView
                style={styles.listContainer}
                dataSource={this.state.dataSource}
                renderRow={rowData => (
                    <View>
                        <Text style={styles.listItem}>{rowData.title}</Text>
                    </View>
                )}
            />
        </View>
    );
}
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
listContainer: {
    paddingTop: 22
},
listItem: {
    fontSize: 30,
    fontWeight: "bold",
    textAlign: "center"
}
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your code, you only set your `dataSource` in `contructor` of `FormativeRevisionList`, this mean `FormativeRevisionList` will only render the given movies when your first render it.

To render new list after you press Get Topics button , you need to set the `dataSource` again when it receive new props, this can be achieve by setting it in `FormativeRevisionList componentWillReceiveProps`

```
  componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {
    if (nextProps.movies !== this.props.movies) {
      this.setState({
        dataSource: this.state.dataSource.cloneWithRows(nextProps.movies)
      })
    }
  }
```

You can read more about componentWillReceiveProps from [here](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/react-component.html#componentwillreceiveprops)

Comment: Worked like a charm. actually I am new to react and don't know about many react functionalities.